# Consecutive double slashes in request url

Tags: nginx, tomcat9

We've recently upgraded tomcat servers from 8.5.24 to 9.0.27 and URLs with
consecutive double slashes that used to work such as
"http://**www.domain.com//stm/stm/restcall/v1/plat**" stopped working - getting a 404.
This happens on our development environments running on Linux.
I searched this change in the release notes but couldn't find any change that may have
caused this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like related to https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61634 and https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61185

From above it was applied to

- trunk for 9.0.0.M22 onwards
- 8.5.x for 8.5.16 onwards
- 8.0.x for 8.0.45 onwards
- 7.0.x for 7.0.79 onwards

Ref http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Bug-61634-New-URLs-with-double-consecutive-slashes-stopped-working-in-8-0-45-in-some-scenarios-td5068667.html